# Lost internal storage space on my Xperia Z1 Compact

Tags: internal-storage, storage, sony-xperia

When I perform this `df mnt/sdcard/` on my Xperia Z1 Compact, I get:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
mnt/sdcard/             11.8G     7.9G     3.9G   4096
```

But when I do `for el in $(ls -a mnt/sdcard/); do du -sh "mnt/sdcard/${el}"; done` I get [that](http://pastebin.com/WHMdGSGN).

So, the sum is much less than 7.9G. Where has the remaining space gone?

Answer (score 2):

Android's internal storage is made up of *many* symbolic links. They point towards different locations of your phone's storage.

`/mnt/sdcard` internally links to `/data/media`. This directory just contains your user data but no applications or application data.
`/data/` contains multiple directories containing the apps (`/data/app`) or the app data (`/data/data`) that all contribute to the used storage.

What you see using `df` is the total storage statistics of the whole partition, even though you run it on `/mnt/sdcard`.
Citing the Linux manual: *df - report file system disk space usage*.
This means it takes into account *all* files and folders on that partition even though you are using a directory of the partition as the parameter.

Conclusion: `df` returns the statistics for the complete partition, but you are just looking at one directory inside of it.